# Using Wildcards in VBA Shell Command

Tags: shell, vba, wildcard

I am using the `Shell_` command in VBA. Are there wildcards allowed with this command? If so what are they?

EX:

```
Shell_ """C:\Program Files\ProgHere\Prog Here v *.*\Prog Here Mini\prog.exe"""
```

Comment: Can you explain what you actually need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The path is simply passed directly to the shell to execute, and the shell can't execute a path with wildcards in it.

What you can do is use the Dir command first (which does allow wildcards) to get the filename you want, then execute it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx